# Woocommerce standard emails gone

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I was trying to add an extra email to the woocommerce emails, following [this tutorial](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/).

Basically, I had gotten this far:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WooCommerce Custom Expedited Order Email
 * Plugin URI: https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/
 * Description: Demo plugin for adding a custom WooCommerce email that sends admins an email when an order is received with expedited shipping
 * Author: SkyVerge
 * Author URI: http://www.skyverge.com
 * Version: 0.1
 *
 * License: GNU General Public License v3.0
 * License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
 *
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
 /**
 *  Add a custom email to the list of emails WooCommerce should load
 *
 * @since 0.1
 * @param array $email_classes available email classes
 * @return array filtered available email classes
 */
function add_expedited_order_woocommerce_email( $email_classes ) {

    // include our custom email class
    require( 'includes/class-wc-expedited-order-email.php' );

    // add the email class to the list of email classes that WooCommerce loads
    $email_classes['WC_Expedited_Order_Email'] = new WC_Expedited_Order_Email();

    return $email_classes;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', 'add_expedited_order_woocommerce_email' );
```

So only the first two steps - mind you, this was without even having the plugin activated, when I checked the email section of woocommerce settings randomly, where normally there is all the standard emails, there was only "new order" sitting there. I have no idea how an unactivated plugin did this, and I don't know how to fix it. Does anyone know how I'd get the emails back? I looked in the ftp and all the php files for them are there, it's just not loading them for some reason..

Comment: Are the emails disabled in the admin settings?

Comment: Nope, and that's what makes me uneasy. It's like the code above deleted them from the database - except I can still see the templates in the ftp :/